# Processing POST form data in C# WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am calling a C# WebAPI with the following request:

```
Request URL: https://devserver/myapp/api/SaveSettings?debug=0
Request Method:POST
Status Code:202 Accepted

Request Headers
...
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
...

Form Data:
config:{"test":"test12"}

Response Headers:
...
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
...
```

The WebAPI application code is

```
public class SaveSettingsController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostComplex(MyModel update)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted,update.config.test);
        }
    }
}
```

While the Status Code is sent correctly (which is why I came to believe that this code is really executed), the content is always null, and I don't know why. I also tried a model with config set to type string, and

```
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted,update.config);
```

but to no avail: it still returns null.

Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you please post the `MyModel` class to verify the data structure which is sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a post parameter in web api you decorate it with the [FromBody] attribute like below:

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostComplex([FromBody] MyModel update)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted,update.config.test);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to create a response and all that complicated stuff, just return any value, it gets jsonized

Comment: I had at first - but I always got a return value of null, not seeing that any code is executed at all. The Response (with Status Code) is just to see that changes in my code have any effect. And - your answer doesn't help with my question...

Answer (score 1):

You request content-type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but you are sending Json data. Either change your content-type to `application/json` or change the format of the request body data.